# average power of signal given the mean and the variance

Tags: signal-power

Let a signal be a random process.Given the mean and variance what is the average  power of the signal.

Comment: Hi! why cannot you find it by yourself ?

Answer (score 1):

Given the variance of the signal $x(t)$, $\text{var}(x(t))$, you can express it as:

$ \text{var}(x(t))=E[ x^2(t) ] - E[x(t)]^2 $

Rearranging you can get the average signal power:

$ E[x^2(t)] = \text{var}(x(t)) + E[x(t)]^2 =\sigma_x^2+\mu_x^2$